# Change style of a bodeplot with many plots in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I've the following script in MATLAB that generates a plot with many bodeplot functions:

```
function bodetest()
  bodesample = tf([3, -2, 1], [4, -5, 5, 6, 3]);
  bodesample2 = tf([1, -1, 1], [4, 7, 5, 6, 3]);
  h = bodeplot([bodesample, bodesample; bodesample, bodesample],[bodesample2, bodesample2; bodesample2, bodesample2]);
end
```

[image]

Now I've the handle stored in `h` variable. How can I change the line color and style for every individual plot programmatically by using the handler?

For example I want to change the green phase plot in position (1, 2) from green to red, and the blue magnitude of the plot in position (2, 1) in black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the conventional way of using the figure handle seems more convenient.

```
%Making desired bodeplots
fh=figure;    %Figure handle
bodeplot([bodesample, bodesample; bodesample, bodesample], ...   %Bodeplot for System-1 
    [bodesample2, bodesample2; bodesample2, bodesample2]);       %Bodeplot for System-2
```

The children of bodeplots are indexed in the reverse order i.e. `fh.Children` are in the following order:

[image: image1]

 <sup>*Fig. Order of `fh.Children`, 1 is the `ContextMenu`*</sup>

Ignore the color of lines in the above figure at the moment (it will be discussed later).

Then going further, the children of `fh.Children` are ordered such that `1` being the first system, `2` being the second system and so on.

The color property of the lines is actually property of the children of the above.

---

### Examples

**For MATLAB R2014a and earlier versions (also applicable on the later versions):**

Looking at the [color of lines](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/why-are-plot-lines-different-colors.html#buhi77f-2) of your bodeplot, it seems that you're using MATLAB R2014a or an earlier version so you would have to use [**`get`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) and [**`set`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html).

1. To change the green-colored phase plot in 1st row & 2nd column to red, use:

   ```
   ch=get(fh,'children');  ch=get(ch(5),'children');  ch=get(ch(2),'children'); 
   % '5' according to the map shown before. And '2' since it is the second system
   set(ch,'color','r');
   ```
2. Similarly to change the blue-colored magnitude plot in 4th row & 1st column to black, use:

   ```
   ch=get(fh,'children');  ch=get(ch(6),'children');  ch=get(ch(1),'children');
   % '6' according to the map shown before. And '1' since it is the first system 
   set(ch,'color','k');
   ```

---

**For MATLAB R2014b and later versions:**

1. To change the green-colored (which is orange in R2014b and later versions) phase plot in 1st row & 2nd column to red, use:

   ```
   fh.Children(5).Children(2).Children.Color = 'r';     
   % '5' according to the map shown before. And '2' since it is the second system
   ```
2. Similarly to change the blue-colored magnitude plot in 4th row & 1st column to black, use:

   ```
   fh.Children(6).Children(1).Children.Color = 'k';
   % '6' according to the map shown before. And '1' since it is the first system
   ```

---

See the short/long names of colors and their RGB triplets in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#input_argument_d0e738935) or specify your own color with its RGB values. Other line properties such as `LineStyle`, `LineWidth`, `MarkerSize` etc can also be changed in the similar way.

<sup>It may also be possible using the bodeplot handle using [**`getoptions`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/getoptions.html) and [**`setoptions`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/setoptions.html).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can extract line handles from the plot and change individual colors via

```
 linehandle = findobj(gcf, 'Type','line');
 set(linehandle(ii), 'Color', [1 1 0]);
```

The problem will be to map a line to a specific plot (the search query finds 24 lines).

It might help to analyze the position of the corresponding axes. For example

```
 linehandle(9).Parent.Parent
```

delivers

```
 Axes with properties:

           XLim: [0.0100 100]
           YLim: [-363.6000 3.6000]
         XScale: 'log'
         YScale: 'linear'
  GridLineStyle: '-'
       Position: [0.5425 0.1100 0.3625 0.1580]
          Units: 'normalized'
```

This might be the bottom right graph. The object search can also be filtered by logical conditions:

```
 lineHandle = findobj(gcf,'Type','line','-and','Color','b');
```

But I am afraid that assigning a line handle to a specific function graph will be try-and-error in the end...

Comment: At first I obtain 24 handles, instead than 16 and I don't know which ones I must to choose. I'd also like to use my `h` handler because my script generates many plots and I want to refer to a specific one. I've tried `linehandle = findobj(h, 'Type','line');` but  I obtain an empty array.

Comment: findobj must be appied to the figure handle or its children. You can also try to browse the figure from the root. When f is your figure handle, have a look at the f.Children object. You will have to identify the right children manually.

Comment: nope... `No appropriate method, property, or field Children for class resppack.bodeplot.`

Comment: Please forget the bodeplot handle. You have to browse though the figure handle. Retrieve it via `f = gcf;` or by manually plotting to axes (`help bodeplot`)